# Execute a powershell function directly in powershell command prompt

Tags: .net, powershell

How can i execute a powershell function directly in a powershell command prompt as follow

```
>>PS C:\Users\tijo.scaria> Function Test-Demo
>> {
>> Param ($Param1)
>> Begin{ write-host "Starting"}
>> Process{ write-host "processing" $_ for $Param1}
>> End{write-host "Ending"}
>> }
```

How can i call this function.
i tied by pressing CNTRL+C and get out of the function and tried following command

```
>>PS C:\Users\tijo.scaria> Echo Testing1, Testing2 | Test-Demo Sample
```

but i got the following error

```
Test-Demo : The term 'Test-Demo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operableprogram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.At line:1 char:27+ Echo Testing1, Testing2 |Test-Demo Sample
```

How can i execute a function directly from Command window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was pressing control-C to abort the function definition instead of completing it by pressing return:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> function Test-Demo
>> {
>> Param ($Param1)
>> Begin { Write-Host "Starting" }
>> Process { Write-Host "Processing" $_ for $Param1 }
>> End { Write-Host "Ending" }
>> }
>>
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-Demo "Hello"
Starting
Processing  for Hello
Ending
```

If you want to play with function definitions interactively though you should use Powershell ISE v3 or later. It makes these things much easier (in ISE you can enter multi-line commands with shift-return and then pull them back as a single coherent command, edit, insert and delete lines) or just type in the file window and execute any selected group of lines).

So in Powershell ISE v3:

```
PS C:\> function Test-Demo
{
 Param ($Param1)
 Begin { Write-Host "Starting" }
 Process { Write-Host "Processing" $_ for $Param1 }
 End { Write-Host "Ending" }
}

PS C:\> Test-Demo "Hello"
Starting
Processing  for Hello
Ending

PS C:\>
```

and then up-arrow twice brings back the entire function definition.

Comment: Since there is no more ISE, using the Microsoft Code editor or the Visual Studio Community version are good choices. Both are free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must create a PS1 file that contains that function. Then simply load that file and call the function you developed:

```
. "FunctionFile.ps1"
Test-Demo "Testing1"
```

Comment: i know that Trinue :-)

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you used Ctrl+C to exit the function. Doing that removes the function.
You must write the function again but instead of using Ctrl+C to exit the prompt (>>) just press Enter.
Then the function will be completed and you will be able to use it.